# multi header columns datagridview save to pdf vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf

creating attendance report in my project. I got a problem is datagridview multiple columns not saving in pdf it is saving only columns not group columns. Could you please help me to fix this problem

datagridview multiple columns on below screenshot[image]
but when I am saving into pdf I am getting only columns but not column headers[image]

below is the code what I tried

```
   Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(dgHours.ColumnCount)
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3
        pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 60
        pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1
        'Adding Header row
        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In dgHours.Columns
            Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(column.HeaderText))
            cell.BackgroundColor = New iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240)
            pdfTable.AddCell(cell)
        Next

        'Adding DataRow
        Dim cellvalue As String = ""
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgHours.Rows
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                cellvalue = cell.FormattedValue
                pdfTable.AddCell(Convert.ToString(cellvalue))
            Next
        Next

        'Exporting to PDF
        Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Users\PC\Pictures\Screenshots\"
        If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
        End If
        Using stream As New FileStream(folderPath & "DataGridViewExport1.pdf", FileMode.Create)
            Dim pdfDoc As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10, 10, 42, 35)
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream)
            pdfDoc.Open()
            pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable)
            pdfDoc.Close()
            stream.Close()
        End Using
```

Comment: How did you get datagridview to have multiple columns?

Comment: thanks for reply using this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/efe8eebc-ed27-4230-9c8e-7248f1c302a7/multiple-layered-column-header?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: Thanks. As for your question, the column does not include the manually painted value, because it really isn't part of the cell's value. That's why it is not included when you export to PDF. You have to also manually set these values when exporting.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I set these values manually...